# ASP vs PHP compiliation

Tags: php, asp.net

I am starting a major project and will be hiring developers soon. Right now im trying to decide between ASP.net and PHP and leaning strongly towards asp as most of the desktop apps will be written in C#

About 50% of this project will be coded into a web system. My question is about how i could secure the code. Does php or asp offer any form of compilation that will not reveal the default source code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a properly secured server, neither will reveal their source code. You should let the programmers have a big say in choosing the tech. No offense, but you are not qualified to make that choice alone.

The biggest issue will be how skilled your team is. If you hire a bunch of .net guys and expect them to code PHP you will have a poorly working site, and  visa-versa.

You should hire some developers or at least your lead developer and talk with her about it.

Since you will be having desktop apps .net seems the logical choice, but there are other issues specific to your business/application you have not considered.

Comment: +1 for involving the people using the tech in the *which-tech* discussion.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: To be fair, you don't know the OP's use case. Maybe he will be distributing his application to customers so they can run on their servers and he wants to ship compiled/obfuscated code to make it difficult/impractical for his customers to deconstruct it.

Comment: @Asaph, very true, but he is a critical juncture that will make or break his project and he should be sitting down with the experts, not posting on SO and hoping he gets the right answer.

Comment: Well i will not be hosting the web servers. Some of these will end up containing helth care data and other stuff that i dont want to be responsible for (other than making sure my code is bug free)

As for the programmers, we are already hiring the .net team for the desktop apps but we would willing to hire a php group if we needed to.

Comment: As you present it, ASP seems to have an upperhand if you can re-use the desktop code on the server.  Having said that, as  PHP fanatic I would seriously re-consider the need for a separate desktop app.  I think Whitlock has expressed the concerns very nicely.

Comment: I guess i could clarify more, right now our team is two people me, CIO and another man who is the CEO and providing angle funding. We don't want to hire a bunch of php programmers and ask them what language we should use.

Comment: Then it seems you have two choices.  Roll the dice or hire a consultant.  If you're a major contributor to the development work, then that needs to be balanced in the decision making too.  Do you have time to learn a new language?  If no - stick with what you know.  With the details given it's not possible to give a valid ASP vs PHP suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is executed from the raw text script files in the exact same form as you compose them. ASP code can be compiled into libraries that you can import.

Moral of story: PHP provides no protection from server-side in-lookers, ASP does if you use the form aforementioned. This is of course assuming that they have some way to get into the server in the first place: both will provide basic protection by hiding the scripts from outsiders.

You can add another form of protection by making sure that the user the scripts are executing under has a strong password and is protected from other users reading, writing or execution.

I would recommend to make the choice based on what you're most comfortable with coding in: you can't beat an egg with a knife.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that I know nothing about ASP.net.  But, as far as PHP is concerned, you have 3 options for securing PHP code:

1. Use [Zend Gaurd](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) to encode and obfuscate the code.  It is, of course, reversible, but having decoded code that was encoded by a less sophisticated mechanism, obfuscated code like this is incredibly tedious to decode and grok.  I haven't used it, so I don't know how it fits into the publishing process, but I assume it's just another step.  Also, if you're going to be installing this software on customer servers, it also offers licensing.
2. Write your the bulk of your proprietary code as php extension (eek!).  That's mostly tongue in cheek, but if it works for you, then it works for you.
3. Secure the code by securing the server.  If this is not going to be on a public server or distributed, then it's not really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Shall we throw say Java and Ruby into the mix to make the conversation even more lively? Pick the technology which you or your team have the most expertise for. They all have their pluses and minuses and the biggest mistake people make is to feel personally attached to any of these

Answer (score 0):

1. Which server O/S (Linux, Windows, Mac)?
2. Which web server (Apache or IIS)?
3. What's the browser compatibility matrix?
4. Silverlight?
5. AJAX? JQuery?
6. Which database?
7. Expected load? Scalability requirement?
8. Web services? SOAP or REST?

My recommendation is regardless of your environment, expose the functionality through web services; it forces MVC separation and gives good hard points for unit testing. Then prototype your web interfaces in both PHP and ASP.Net and see what you like.

If you're hosting the app yourself then hiding the code won't be an issue. If you're selling it then you're stuck having to obfuscate, but there's good tools for both environments.